# Error al subir comillas dobles o simples a una base de datos

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, base-de-datos, input-file

Tengo mi función que lee un documento `*.TXT` y guarda todo el texto que contenga un una variable, para que luego el texto de la variable pueda ser enviada a una base de datos

Mi función cumple su propósito y funciona perfectamente, pero hay un pequeño problema,
si dentro del `*.TXT`, tiene comillas dobles o comillas simples `"" '''''` pues la base de datos no me deja subirla.

En caso contrario no tenga comillas  dobles o simples, el texto se sube exitosamente.

**Entiendo el problema de las comillas, causan problemas, pero...**
**¿hay alguna otra manera de subir texto sin tener ese problema?**

```py
# Abre el archivo
f = open (pathN ,'r')
data = f.read()
f.close()
currentTime = "Tiempo"

sql = "INSERT INTO TableName(user, time, log) VALUES('"+str(getuser())+"','"+currentTime+"','"+data+"')"   
try:
    cursor.execute(sql) 
    onnection.commit() 
    connection.close()
except:
    print("[Database] Error al subir los datos")
```

Answer (score 2):

Cuando hay comillas en la propia cadena, estás generando queries inválidas del tipo:

```
VALUES('""Hola""')
VALUES('"'''Hola'''"')
```

Nunca debes usar formateo o concatenación de cadenas para asignar los valores a tu query, parametriza siempre. Aparte de los posibles errores como el que nos trae entre manos y la poca legibilidad del código, es un problema de seguridad, expones a tu base de datos a ataques de inyección de código.

```
with open(pathN , 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

current_time = "Tiempo"

sql = "INSERT INTO TableName(user, time, log) VALUES(?, ?, ?)"
try:
    cursor.execute(sql, (getuser(), current_time, data)) 
except:
    print("[Database] Error al subir los datos")
finally:
    connection.commit() 
    connection.close()
```

Comment: Me marca error, teniendo no el texto comillas

![Foto de Error](https://i.imgur.com/jjCT8xx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Logré solucionar el error insertando los datos de ésta manera:

```py
sql = "INSERT INTO keyLog(l_user, l_time, l_log) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)"

cursor.execute(sql,("NombreUser","Fecha","Datos"))
connection.commit()
```